# how to display custom fields from custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I used "Advanced Custom Fields" and "Custom Post Type UI" plugins to create a custom post type and custom fields. I used them, and they worked for me. I created a new post type called "Videos", and I turned on the archive page for it, and I created the custom fields that I need (I only do URL input), and also I created the taxonomy called "playlist", and everything is going ok. But now, when I go to the single page of a video, I see no content in the post, no URL, no video platform name, and no data is appearing. I can't see any of the custom fields. Also, I want to design the archive page for videos.

I am using WPBakery Page Builder. I searched on the internet and youtube, and I found solutions using Elementor, but I didn't find any solution with WPBakery. Can anybody help?

The Plugin Code to create the custom post type:

**Videos Post Type:**

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Videos.
     */

    $labels = [
        "name" => __( "Videos", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Video", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "featured_image" => __( "Thumbnail Image", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "set_featured_image" => __( "Set Thumbnail Image", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "remove_featured_image" => __( "Remove Thumbnail Image", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "use_featured_image" => __( "Use Thumbnail Image", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    ];

    $args = [
        "label" => __( "Videos", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "videos", "with_front" => true ],
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-format-video",
        "supports" => [ "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ],
        "show_in_graphql" => false,
    ];

    register_post_type( "videos", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts' );
```

**Playlists Taxonomy:**

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_playlist() {

    /**
     * Taxonomy: Playlists.
     */

    $labels = [
        "name" => __( "Playlists", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Video Playlist", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    ];

    
    $args = [
        "label" => __( "Playlists", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'playlist', 'with_front' => true, ],
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "show_tagcloud" => true,
        "rest_base" => "playlist",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
        "show_in_graphql" => false,
    ];
    register_taxonomy( "playlist", [ "videos" ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_playlist' );
```

**Custom Field:**

```
        if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_615b37c91ca00',
    'title' => 'Videos',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_615b37f59afc2',
            'label' => 'Video URL',
            'name' => 'video_url',
            'type' => 'url',
            'instructions' => 'insert YouTube url.',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'https://youtu.be/******',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'videos',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
));

endif;
```

Comment: _"I can't see any of the custom fields"_ - well what exactly did you do, to make them show up? You did not expect that to happen automatically, did you ...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a single file for the videos post type. You can easily create into your theme folder which name is must single-videos.php. single post template code example idea share below.

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <span><?php the_field('video_url'); ?></span>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

I hope you see something that you expected.
**Note:** Must be flush permalink.